# layout_alignParentEnd and backward compatibility

Tags: android

I am currently working on making an android app compatible with more devices by lowering the required SDK version.
For unimplemented features such as Notifications and such, I have been able to use the Android Support Library which solved everything easily.

However, when it comes to layouts, I'm facing some issues I'm unsure how to tackle.
I'm using the following attributes which were only introduced in API 17:
`layout_alignParentEnd`, `layout_marginEnd` and `layout_alignParentStart`. Of course, removing them completely beaks my layouts.

Is there a way to use the Android Support Library to have them reintroduced?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android:layout_alignParentLeft` can be used to replace `android: layout_alignParentStart`

`android:layout_alignParentRight` can be used to replace `android: layout_alignParentEnd`

And likewise, `android:layout_marginRight` can be used to replace `android: layout_marginEnd`